# Python mod_wsgi is not working

Tags: python, wsgi

I use Python Flask on Centos 6 server, and mod_wsgi is not working suddenly.

here is the error message.

```
mod_wsgi (pid=6206): Target WSGI script '/home/bridge/index.wsgi' does not contain WSGI application 'application'.
```

here is the apis.wsgi file.

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'/home/bridge/apis')
from apis import app as application

import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
```

here is the index.py file.

```
from apis import app
```

I haven't changed anything on server. All I did was restart the server. Is there someone who knows about this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try looking at this: http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/InstallationIssues

It lists many issues with the modwsgi. Good luck on this fix!

You might of accidentally edited your code and messed things up. Double check.